# Exclude a single last word from string using capture groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing an integer parser in Javascript that takes in verbal descriptions of numbers up to a million. At the moment, I need to get rid of `(space)thousand` in a string like `two hundred forty-two thousand`, most preferably using a capture group containing the `two hundred forty-two`. My problem is, the `thousand` may or may not be there, and using `?` in this case stops my regex from working as intended. Here's what I've got so far:

Considering the string `two hundred forty-two thousand`

- with `(.* ?)( thousand)` first capture group contains `two hundred forty-two`, but it doesn't work if the string doesn't end with `thousand`
- `(.* ?)( thousand)?` works without the `thousand` in the string, but first capture group yields the entire string at all times

What I need is an expression that puts the whole string in a capture group, except the last, specified word *whether it exists or not* in the string.

I've been searching a lot for a solution to this, but I couldn't find anywhere a case in which the excluded word is optional in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var re = /^(.*?)( thousand)?$/;
console.log("two hundred forty-two thousand".match(re));
console.log("two hundred forty-two".match(re));
```

1. Anchor the match at the beginning and the end of the string.
2. Use `.*?` to match lazily (i.e. non-greedily) up to an optional `thousand`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a non capturing group to match the `thousand` pattern and discard it if present, if it is not there the alternation will match until the end of line.

I can come up with this regex:

```
(.+?)(?: thousand|$)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/hA8mE7/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[image]